Why Knowledge__kav.LastModifiedDate field is not available for a formula field?
This is very strange behavior.
While it is possible to see LastModifiedDate in the Knowledge__kav object, it is not possible to reference it in a formula field. Why?
If we try to create a file LMD__c.field-meta.xml with a content
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>LMD__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <formula>LastModifiedDate</formula>
    <formulaTreatBlanksAs>BlankAsZero</formulaTreatBlanksAs>
    <label>LMD</label>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>DateTime</type>
</CustomField>

and try to deploy it using
sf force:source:deploy -m CustomField:Knowledge__kav.LMD__c

we receive an error Field LastModifiedDate does not exist. Check spelling. (52:13) 
but it definitely exists as we can read in this article.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387293&type=1
What is wrong here?
